# ERROR 10401 payment order total is invalid

Tags: php, paypal

when users upload some files, the price tag for some files comes out as 2.97211$ instead of 2.97$ which leads to a

> ERROR: #10401: Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See
>   additional error messages for details. [Order total is invalid.]

error when they try to check out with the payment gateway.

Here is the code that is giving the problem

```
$filesize = filesize($file) * .0009765625; // bytes to KB
```

I have tried changing the .0009765625 variable to many different values .1002345625 .2342335622 etc etc to no avail.

I've also tried changing this part of the code.

```
else{return round($filesize, 2);}
```

to else{return round($filesize 0.02, 2);} which inflates the price to 400.52$ which makes the item unpayable.

How do i force the price to remain at 0.00$ instead of 0.00000$?

Comment: maybe more context needed? what is filesize got to do with price? How is the price calculated? Round will work, as long as it is the last operation.

Comment: When people are uploading files to our server, the php script calculates the size of the file being uploaded and translates it to a price, the bigger the file the bigger the price. That part of the script was giving problems that's why i posted it.

Answer (score -1):

Use php number_format function

```
$formatted = number_format(filesize($fileName), 2, '.', '');
```

Comment: Sorry but this code doesn't appear to be working, it just shifts the "." in the price tag around, that's all.